# webpack nodeExternals need to give dependent module of dependent

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack to build a bundled file for my node environment.  Part of this is using nodeExternals.  My code is dependent on graphql and I have the following in my webpack

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './src/main'
    },
    watch: false,
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals({
        whitelist: ['graphql']
    })],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            use: 'babel-loader'
        }]
    },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    }
}
```

Now when I run this I get an error saying cannot find module 'iterall' which is something which graphql is dependent on.  As soon as I include this in the whitelist of nodeExternals then it works.  My question is, shouldn't this dependency be automatically included since I am already saying graphql is whitelisted?  If not how do I find all the dependencies and I assume this would be a tedious process.